# Return Custom HTTP Status Code from WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, http-status-codes

You can return the http status code along with the response object using:

```
 return Ok(responseObject);
 return BadRequest(responseObject);
 return NotFound(responseObject);
```

But what about you want to return your own custom http status code? 402, 429, 500, 501 etc

Comment: presumably `Ok`, `BadRequest` etc implement some interface that you can also implement in a userland class and return an instance of that class?

Comment: why did you ask this question?

Comment: @Steve It's a suggested way to save a knowledge to answer your answers by yourself. Thats why SO has a `Self-Learner` badge

Answer (score 5):

```
return StatusCode(402, responseObject);
return StatusCode(500, responseObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Response.StatusCode = 500; // HttpStatusCode.
return responseObject;
```

OR

```
Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError; // HttpStatusCode.
return responseObject;
```